# Delphi monitoring status of CapsLock key

Tags: delphi, winapi

My program runs in the background, and uses a timer to regularly check if Capslock is ON or OFF.

My question is if there exists a better solution than using a timer?

```
procedure TForm1.Timer2Timer(Sender: TObject);
var KeyState: TKeyboardState;
begin
  GetKeyboardState(KeyState) ;
 if (KeyState[VK_CAPITAL] = 0) then
  CheckBox1.Checked:=False //Capslock is OFF
 else
  CheckBox1.Checked:=True; //Capslock is ON
end;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do this with a low level keyboard hook, `WH_KEYBOARD_LL`. Install the hook with `SetWindowHookEx`. You'll get notified of every keyboard event in the hook proc. Detect the original state by calling `GetKeyboardState`.

Note that you must read the documentation more carefully. For `GetKeyboardState` it says:

> If the key is a toggle key, for example CAPS LOCK, then the low-order bit is 1 when the key is toggled and is 0 if the key is untoggled.

Therefore it is erroneous to test the entire byte against zero. Test just the low-order bit. Use `and $1` to pick out that bit.

Answer (score 0):

KeyPreview:= True

```
    FormKeyUp(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
    begin
     if GetKeyState(VK_CAPITAL) > 0 then
        hdrSts.Sections[0]:= 'CAPS LOCK'
      else
        hdrSts.Sections[0]:= '';
    end;
```